# Xcode Storyboard - Table View doesn't expand automatically when dragged in

Tags: xcode, storyboard, tableview

In Xcode 7.3, when I drag in a Table View from the Object Library to the Storyboard for a single view app, it doesn't automatically expand to the full size of the view. I seen it do that in my Udacity class videos and in other videos on YouTube. Is there a setting in Xcode that will correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to "pin" the tableView at the ViewController. Am I right you have a simple ViewController and add a tableView to it?

Now, you need to open the Pin Menu and uncheck the checkbox "Constrains to margins". Now you add the constrains to the top, left, right and bottom to 0 and save it. Now the TableView should stretch the whole display.

If you only show a table in the ViewController you should use a UITableViewController.

Comment: You are right that I'm dragging the tableView into a simple ViewController. Although your idea is not exactly the same as what I saw in the videos (the tableView automatically expanding to the full size of the view), it does do what I need without the need to drag the border of the tableView. Thanks!